# MongoDB compass stalls on "activating plugins" screen

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

Just installed version 1.21.1 and on initial start-up it stalls on this screen with the following [error in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PsczQ.png)

```
loading.js:29 Error: spawnSync wmic UNKNOWN
at Object.spawnSync (internal/child_process.js:1041:20)
at Object.spawnSync (child_process.js:615:24)
at Function.module.exports.sync ...
```

Comment: I believe it is fixed in Compass 1.21.2. You can download it from https://www.mongodb.com/download-center/compass

Answer (score 0):

Mine is still not working, I had the latest version installed.. But I am not sure why. The error is the same though.

Answer (score 0):

try to use Isolated Edition. I had the same problem before. Download Isolated Edition, all run smooth after that.

Answer (score 0):

1.Download and install the mongoDB compass from this link https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/compass?tck=docs_compass

2.For the windows system edit the environmental variable and add below line to path variable as shown in the screenshot.

C:\Windows\System32\wbem

[image]